# React, Redux. Why my dispatch dispatches function body?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Here is my store creation, i'm applying `redux-thunk` in `applyMiddleware` function

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
// import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import tokenReducer from './reducers/tokenReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  tokenReducer
})

const middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, promise, thunk)

let store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware)

export default store
```

Then i connect my component to store and `mapDispatchToProps`

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    getToken: () => dispatch(fetchTokenFromStorage())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SplashScreen)
```

Here is my code of function `fetchTokenFromStorage`

```
export function fetchTokenFromStorage () {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getToken())
    AsyncStorage.getItem('AuthToken')
      .then(function (token) {
        dispatch(getTokenSuccess(token))
      })
      .catch(function () {
        dispatch(getTokenFailure())
      })
  }
}
```

After execution of `this.props.getToken()`
In my console action looks like this:

> action      ƒ (dispatch) {
>       dispatch(getToken());
>       _reactNative.AsyncStorage.getItem('AuthToken').then(function (token) {
>         dispatch(getTokenSuccess(token));
>       }).catch(function () {
>         dispatch(get…

It's my function `fetchTokenFromStorage` code. React transforms my function as action type name. Why?

Comment: I am facing the same problem and your solution doesn't work. Do you have any other alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thunk must be first in `applyMiddleware`

`const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger, promise)`